# Telling PhpStorm where a class is located so it can use autocomplete

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I'm using WordPress and using a plugin called [Timber](https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber-library/), which basically helps you to utilise the Twig templating engine in WordPress.

Anyway, I am trying to do this in one of my files:

```
Timber::render('welcome.twig');
```

PhpStorm is reporting that `Timber` is an unrecognized class, because it doesn't see where I have included it; I assume it is being auto-loaded somewhere?

Now, I did a search around and came across answers about using PHPDoc such as [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207065195-How-to-tell-PhpStorm-class-variable-type), however I'm not sure how to apply that to my situation, I tried:

```
/** @var \Timber\Timber */
```

...but it didn't seem to work.

If I can somehow do this globally that would be great, so I don't have to do it in every file I need to use Timber in.

Comment: Your `Timber` seems to be namespaced class (based on your `/** @var \Timber\Timber */` attempt). So .. all you need is to write `use Timber\Timber;` on top of the file where it is used. Otherwise ... you need to make some "fake" class just for IDE: e.g. `class Timber extends \Timber\Timber {}` and it has to be in global namespace. You do not have to include this file anywhere -- it's for IDE only.

Comment: Hmm yeah I thought the namespace may be affecting it, but it seems to work - functionally - without me having to reference the namespace.

Comment: It works because it's already `use`d elsewhere (the `use` clause). Or maybe there is a code that handles such stuff during runtime. But IDE is not aware of that magic ... so you have to tell it what `Timebr::` is. Generally speaking, for me it's similar to **facades in Laravel** (the way how they are used). IDE helper package creates fake classes for IDE only .. so it understands such class references. I'm pretty sure it will be the same here (the solution).

Comment: That's the package -- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper -- you may find already generated file with fakes in description if desired.

Comment: OK thanks - I will give it a look :)

Comment: Have you tried it? Any issues?

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah, using the fake class worked like a charm :)